# Generate ipa for iPhone 4,4S,5 and iPad

Tags: iphone, ios

I have generated ipa for my application with the architectures as `armv6`,`armv7`,`armv7s` with adhoc certificate where all the required `UDID`'s are included in the adhoc profile and created ipa using `Archive` process but they cacot instal the app they are getting the itunes Sync failed  can any one help

Comment: are you sure created ipa file is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to send Adhoc profile also to the user if user want to install the app through iTunes so both the ipa and profile should drag and drop into the iTunes and sync it. if we go and down load it from Appstore we need not do it because apple will take care of it

I think if we use provising profile also we need to do this

Answer (score 1):

Note that **armv6** was deprecated when iPhone 5 go out.

> **Xcode 4.5** doesn't permit you to buil an ipa for armv6 devices (iphone
>   3G), only for armv7 and armv7s.
>   And **Xcode < 4.5** doesn't permit you to
>   build an armv7s... How you can made it all toghether?

The sync error come on iphone 3G? If yes, it's normal, your ipa is not compatible with this phone...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your direct question, but you could try using [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/). It makes the process of distributing Ad Hoc builds a breeze, completely outside of iTunes. It's free, by the way.